# I have keys but no locks

Tags: riddle

I have keys but no locks.

I have space but no walls.

You can enter, but you can't leave.

What am I?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Answer:

> A keyboard from before the computer mass market

I have keys but no locks.

> Keyboards have keys, but modern keyboards include **Caps Lock**. Early computers only had upper case letters, so there was no need for a caps lock.

I have space but no walls.

> Spacebar

You can enter, but you can't leave.

> The Enter key (sometimes called Return)

Comment: Made it the best answer because it answered the Caps Lock part.

Answer (score 3):

Answer:

> A keyboard

I have keys but no locks:

> The keys on a keyboard

Space but no walls:

> Spacebar but no walls

Enter but not leave:

> Enter key

Comment: Mine has a caps lock.

Answer (score 1):

> Keyboard

I have keys but no locks.

> All the keys

I have space but no walls.

> Space key

You can enter, but you can't leave.

> Enter key